# org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath

Tags: java, spring, tomcat7

Below is the log i get from tomcat localhost.log file, though the .war is being deployed to tomcat webapp folder successfully without any errors, when i try to access the war through the tomcat manager gui, it always gives a 404 error, would be great if anyone could point me whats wrong and i also tried almost all the solutions people have posted for this kind of error previously, none worked so far :

```
10-Aug-2016 16:50:18.116 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-18] org.apache.catalina.core

.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
10-Aug-2016 16:51:41.073 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-20] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
10-Aug-2016 17:19:16.874 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-25] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
10-Aug-2016 17:19:16.914 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-25] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
10-Aug-2016 17:19:17.841 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-25] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
```

Re-Edit: This is the pom.xml file im using

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    com.surrey.neo
    DemoTestNeo
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    war

```
<properties>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    <deploy.name>neo4jTest</deploy.name>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Tomcat plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <path>/${deploy.name}</path>
                    <update>true</update>
                    <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                    <username>tomcat</username>
                    <password>tomcat</password>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <overlays>
                        <overlay>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.jsp</include>
                            </includes>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF/pages</targetPath>
                        </overlay>
                    </overlays>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${deploy.name}/WEB-INF/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <useProjectReferences>false</useProjectReferences>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

</build>
```

2nd edit: **web.xml** file im using currently

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    metadata-complete="true">

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>
     contextConfigLocation
    </param-name>
    <param-value>
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
   <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Comment: Please post how do you build your war and what does it contain. Thanks

Comment: Please post web.xml